# How to access packages created in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android and stuck at point. Please help!

I have created a dummy Hello world program (with project name testneha) in android studio. I created a new package "AppTest" folder inside the "com.example.ospune.testneha" folder. Inside the package, have created a JAVA class file with name AppTest1. 
Folder Structure

```
com.example.ospune.test
    AppTest(package folder)
       AppTest1(java file)
    MainActivity(file)
```

In AppTest1 file, onCreate folder I am calling "apptest layout file".

Now In the mainActivity file, I have added a button; which on being clicked calls startActivity mentioned in the AppTest1 class.

`public void sendMessage(View view)
{ 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.ospune.test.neha.AppTest.AppTest1.class");
startActivity(intent);
}`

My problem is when I click the button, I get a pop up saying "unfortunately, Test has stopped."

AndroidManifest.xml was also updated with the AppTest1.class activity

`<activity
     android:name=".AppTest.AppTest1"
     android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
</activity>`

I am clueless as what is the reason for this :(

LogCat error -

```
11-03 04:34:43.409 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-03 04:34:43.410 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha I/art: Late-enabling JIT
11-03 04:34:43.419 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-03 04:34:43.507 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha-2/lib/x86
11-03 04:34:43.914 2055-2083/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-03 04:34:43.918 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad7f0110, tid 2055
11-03 04:34:44.008 2055-2083/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad7f0420, tid 2083
11-03 04:34:44.033 2055-2083/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-03 04:34:44.145 2055-2083/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-03 04:34:44.145 2055-2083/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabebf2c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-03 04:34:45.360 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-03 04:35:03.158 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha, PID: 2055
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha.AppTest.AppTest1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:100)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:93)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:206)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha.AppTest.AppTest1.onCreate(AppTest1.java:22)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-03 04:35:03.159 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-03 04:35:07.335 2055-2055/com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2055 SIG: 9
```

Comment: hey neha show me you error logs, it doesn't happen with me when i started with android studio

Comment: Add you error and code also

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: show your error : logcat

Comment: MainActivity.java file

Comment: MainActivity

public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.ospunelap_130.testneha.AppTest.AppTest1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: AppTest1 file

public class AppTest1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apptest);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}

Comment: Error is shown when I am running the app on the emulator. On Phone, it just exits!

Comment: @Neha Error logs..please

Comment: @Androider: added error logs. Thanks!

Comment: @Droidwala: Added error logs

Comment: @Neha can you post your complete code for class **AppTest1**

Comment: Dear @Droidwala, I could solve with the help of another member.

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt replies !!

Comment: toolbar.getTitle() is the problem, which is null, check it own

Comment: @Neha No problem..Welcome to SO!! :)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
The error is due to invoking toolbar.getTitle() method. The toolbar object is returning null. Try this:

`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findviewById(R.id.toolbar);`

to initialize the toolbar. The error is at line no. 22 according to logcat.

Comment: Which IDE are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: The error is due to invoking toolbar.getTitle() method. The toolbar object is returning null.
Try this:

'Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findviewById(R.id.toolbar);'

to initialize the toolbar. The error is at line no. 22 according to logcat.